# MS Outlook - Rectify Calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

At my workplace we have a master calendar, which is viewable by everyone using Outlook.  We also have individual calendars, which are viewable only when logged in with the associated email account (so I can't see my coworker's individual calendars and they can't see mine, but we can all see the master calendar).  Is there a way to have the master calendar automatically update my calendar as well, so any task added to the master calendar will also be added to my calendar automatically?

If it is relevant, I am using Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to automatically propagate appts and tasks. If you have the master calendar and your personal calendar open side-by-side you can drag appts from one to the other. If you hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while dropping the item it will also create a copy on your calendar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but unfortunately the corporate calendar has far too many events for this to be viable.

Comment: Are you trying to have all events copied to your calendar? For what purpose? More info might help suggest a better option. You can overlay calendars if you just want to see them in one view (see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/microsoft-office/overlay-calendars-in-outlook-2007-like-google-calendar-does/)

Comment: In order to access them from my boss's iPhone, apparently because the master calendar is not tied with his account, it is impossible for him to access (?).